# Why doesn't SO have auto-complete

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, answers

Can SO put some auto-complete capabiliity, e.g. NPE -> NullPointerException, etc.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @KennyTM - As I said, if you type NPE and tab it should become NullPointerException.

Comment: Don't we have enough to worry about with tag synonyms?

Comment: Yeah. This is really a client side task, not a feature for SO

Comment: its better to develop a IDE for SO... SO Studio 2011

Answer (score 6):

Let me put this very simply.

**I've never coded a line of java in my life.**

Do you really want my favorite `awk` expressions polluting your abbreviation space?

Comment: oh god no, the horror

Answer (score 4):

You can code in your favorite IDE with autocompletion enabled and copy and paste the code snippet.

Stack Overflow is designed to be language agnostic. Even in the same language, an abbreviation may mean a different thing in another context.

Answer (score 2):

I think auto-complete things would be handy for instance in comments for @ replies(for instance, @d (tab) would yield @dmckee) but what you are asking for is a complete maintenance nightmare for very little gain.

Comment: Prescient! (I assume. I don't feel like checking on whether you were actually the first to suggest this.)

Answer (score 0):

Complete autocomplete will very difficult. Some simple things can be done depending on the tag. If 'java' they can put `java` specific autocomplete, etc. As Earlz said some common autocomplete can be provided.